# Dynamic UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join

I want to create a dynamic update query where I need to set a certain value in a column. But the column name needs to be SELECTed from another table.
I have already the following query:

```
UPDATE core.TableRes
SET (
    SELECT Code FROM core.TableFields 
    INNER JOIN core.TableXTableFields ON TableXTableFields.FieldID = TableFields.FieldID 
    INNER JOIN core.TableResRefLinks ON TableResRefLinks.ExtraFieldID = TableXTableFields.ExtraFieldID 
    WHERE TableResRefLinks.TableResRefLinksID = RefLinks.TableResRefLinksID)
= (
    SELECT Value FROM core.TableResRefLinks WHERE TableResRefLinksID = RefLinks.TableResRefLinksID)
FROM core.TableRes
    INNER JOIN core.TableResRefLinks RefLinks ON RefLinks.ResourceID = TableRes.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN core.TableXTableFields ON TableXTableFields.ExtraFieldID = RefLinks.ExtraFieldID
    INNER JOIN core.TableFields ON TableFields.FieldID = TableXTableFields.FieldID
    WHERE (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate > GETDATE()) AND
    (
        SELECT Code FROM core.TableFields 
        INNER JOIN core.TableXTableFields ON TableXTableFields.FieldID = TableFields.FieldID 
        INNER JOIN core.TableResRefLinks ON TableResRefLinks.ExtraFieldID = TableXTableFields.ExtraFieldID 
        WHERE TableResRefLinks.TableResRefLinksID = RefLinks.TableResRefLinksID) 
    <>
    (
        SELECT Value FROM core.TableResRefLinks 
        WHERE TableResRefLinksID = RefLinks.TableResRefLinksID)
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
```

Is there a way to solve this? If I change the complete UPDATE and SET statements and replace them with a SELECT *, I get results.

EDIT
Here are the datatypes
TableFields.Code => nvarchar(100)
TableResRefLinks.Value => sql_variant
And the datatypes of the columns that have as column name TableFields.Code are set as sql_variant

Comment: AFAIK you can't dynamically determine the field that you are updating with a select query.  Additionally, you can't retrieve its value with a select statement like that because you could end up in a situation where the query would be trying to populate one field with multiple value returned from the select.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification. I've made a SELECT where I create the UPDATE query and then I can simply run all those queries easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve this using plain SQL. You would need some kind of scripting to build your statement. For example postgresql has a scripting language called "pgpsql" which allows building dynamic SQL statements. But this clearly depends on the underlying RDBMS.

By the way: this works with SELECT as you are doing simple sub-select.